# Error date_modify() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime

Tags: php, date

Full code :

```
$ngayhientai = date("d/m/Y");
        $ngaygiao = date_create($ngayhientai,timezone_open("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"));
        $ngaygiao = date_modify($ngayhientai,"+3 days");
        $ngaygiao = date_format($ngayhientai,"d/m/Y") ;

        echo $ngaygiao;
```

Error :

```
Warning: date_modify() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\weblazada\dulieu.php on line 8

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\weblazada\dulieu.php on line 9
```

Help me!Thank you everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) only retrieves a formatted date as a string.

The [date_modify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-modify.php) function is an alias of [DateTime::modify()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) which is a part of [Date\Time library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

So, for your case, you can do this:

```
$ngayhientai = new \DateTime();
```

Or

```
$ngayhientai = date_create();
```

And the rest use as OO:

```
$ngayhientai->modify("+3 days");
echo $ngayhientai->format("d/m/Y");
```

It doesn't necessary to save in another variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ngaygiao = date_create(date("d-m-Y"), timezone_open("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"));
$ngaygiao = date_modify($ngaygiao, "+3 days");
$ngaygiao = date_format($ngaygiao, "d/m/Y") ;

echo $ngaygiao;
```

The functions require a native DateTime object, and you're not using the correct variable in some cases.

Comment: Still that error :((

Comment: @S.Luu Accidentally changed something for the worse when editing, sorry about that! Should work now (I even tested).